# Why doesn't Stack Overflow sort by votes anymore?

Tags: bug, voting, up-votes, sorting, answer-order

Within the last week or so, I noticed Stack Overflow no longer sorts by number of votes. Aside from the answer with the most votes, which does seem to come first, the rest of the answers seem to be in a random order. What's going on here?

ex: [Branch descriptions in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git)

Notice the answers here have 195, then 3, then 29 votes. The 3 should come after the 29!

There's also a 17, 40, and 28, in that order, far after the 29 here too. what's going on!? And this isn't just this one answer, this is happening with nearly *every* answer I've looked at over the past week or so.

It makes finding the top few best answers quickly really difficult.

[image]

Comment: Choose the [Votes] Tab not the [Active] Tab, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SpMR.jpg

Comment: How did you take that screenshot so tall? Clearly it doesn't all fit on one screen on your monitor...

Comment: My screenshot (Galaxy S9+) has all sorts of features including the full-page shot. The reason for posting the comment was to explain that I couldn't reproduce the bug and could see from your screenshot what the problem was; also the answer from goldPseudo didn't appear until after I posted my comment and refreshed the page.

Comment: Ah, I see: you're on a phone doing screenshots. Thanks, and I see why your comment came up later now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this?

> [image: "Active" tab: Answers with the latest activity first]

You want this instead.

> [image: "Votes" tab: Answers with the highest score first]

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks! Side note: what image editor did you use for that? I have found great success with Shutter (`sudo apt install shutter` in Ubuntu). If using Ubuntu 18.04, you'll need this fix though to enable Shutter's "edit" button again: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029085/how-to-enable-the-edit-button-in-shutter/1029101#1029101.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Nothing more than the prtsc key and MS Paint.

Comment: Ah, you're on Windows. Try [Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/) or the [Windows Snipping Tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipping_Tool). I think you'll find them more user-friendly and faster to use. On Linux, nothing I've seen beats [Shutter](https://shutter-project.org/)!